# Getting metrics out of AWS Cloudwatch using Java API:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get metrics out of Amazon CloudWatch using the Java SDK. 
I can find examples of listing out metrics. But just can't find any full example showing how to retrieve values for a metric for a given period.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the GetMetricDataRequest [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatch.html#getMetricData-com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.GetMetricDataRequest-)?

Should be straight forward. Something along these lines. (Note, I haven't tested the code).

```
        final GetMetricDataRequest getMetricDataRequest = new GetMetricDataRequest();
        final MetricDataQuery metricDataQuery = new MetricDataQuery();
        metricDataQuery.setId("METRIC_ID");
        final MetricStat metricStat = new MetricStat();
        final Metric metric = new Metric();
        final Dimension dimension = new Dimension();
        nodeCountMetric.setNamespace(namespace);
        dimension.setName("DIMENSION_KEY");
        dimension.setValue("value");


        metric.setDimensions(Collections.singletonList(dimension));
        metric.setMetricName(metricName);
        metricStat.setMetric(metric);
        metricStat.setPeriod(SECONDS_60);
        metricStat.setStat(SAMPLE_COUNT_STATISTIC);
        metricDataQuery.setMetricStat(metricStat);
        getMetricDataRequest.setMetricDataQueries(Collections.singletonList(metricDataQuery));
        final Date endTime = new Date();
        getMetricDataRequest.setEndTime(endTime);
        getMetricDataRequest.setStartTime(new Date(endTime.getTime() - HOURS_3));

        final AmazonCloudWatch cw =
    AmazonCloudWatchClientBuilder.defaultClient();

        GetMetricDataResult metricData = cw.getMetricData(metricDataRequest);
```

Comment: Ankit, thank you for your effort, it got me a bit further but not all the way.

Comment: What issue you are facing now?

Comment: what about getting multiple metric data in single call ?

Answer (score -1):

```
List<MetricDataQuery> metricDataQueries = new ArrayList<>();

String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
int period = 5;
String unit = "bytes/sec"
String metricName = "DiskWriteOps"

uuid = uuid.toLowerCase().replace("-", "_");
MetricStat metStat = MetricStat.builder()
        .stat("Average")
        .period(period)
        .unit(unit)
        .metric(metricName)
        .build();

MetricDataQuery mdq = MetricDataQuery.builder()
        .metricStat(metStat)
        .id(uuid)
        .returnData(true)
        .build();

metricDataQueries.add(mdq);


String uuid2 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
int period2 = 5;
String unit2 = "bytes/sec"
String metricName2 = "DiskReadOps"

uuid2 = uuid2.toLowerCase().replace("-", "_");
MetricStat metStat2 = MetricStat.builder()
        .stat("Average")
        .period(period2)
        .unit(unit2)
        .metric(metricName2)
        .build();

MetricDataQuery mdq2 = MetricDataQuery.builder()
        .metricStat(metStat2)
        .id(uuid2)
        .returnData(true)
        .build();

metricDataQueries.add(mdq2);



GetMetricDataRequest getMetReq = GetMetricDataRequest.builder()
                                .scanBy(ScanBy.TIMESTAMP_DESCENDING)
                                .startTime(<StartTime>)
                                .endTime(<EndTime>)
                                .metricDataQueries(metricDataQueries)
                                .build();
Future<GetMetricDataResponse> future = <CloudwatchAsyncClient>.getMetricData(getMetReq);

....
...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).